# Why isn't the union of a left and right ideal a two-sided ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it because not all rings are commutative? How could we construct a two-sided ideal?

I was thinking of the union of the left (or right) ideal multiplied on the right (or left) by all the elements in the ring.

My notation:
$A$ is a subset of a ring $R$. $I$ is the left ideal $RA$. $J$ is the right ideal $AR$. I was thinking of $K$ being two-sided ideal, where $K = \{ rI : r \in R \}$ or $K = \{ Jr : r \in R \}$.

Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset math on this site using mathjax/latex (it's really easy to learn).

Comment: Ah cool I didn't know I could just use latex on here, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't the union of a left and right ideal a two-sided ideal?

Throughout I use L for a left ideal and T for a right ideal. There is more than one way for the union of L and T to fail to be a two sided ideal.

- if neither of L and T contains the other, then the union is not even a group. This is an easy exercise.
- if one contained the other, the union is just the larger one, and there is no reason that should magically become two sided.

There are at least two natural ways to make an ideal using L and T. You could obviously look at $(L,T)$, for example, but that us sort if a copout.

The other way us to form the product $LT$ which is the set of finite sums of elements of the form xy with x in L and y in T. And yes, you can individually make them into ideals as $LR$ and $RT$.

> Is it because not all rings are commutative?

No, this isn't the cause. Even the union of two sided ideals in a commutative ring might not be an ideal.